# Better distribution of seed based random between 2 lists

Tags: javascript, random, probability, random-seed

I have a list containing 100 'friends'. Part of it looks like:

```
Tetris.friends = 
[
    {
        name: "Haroon Bean",
        file_name: "haroon_bean"
    },
    {
        name: "Nathan Cain",
        file_name: "nathan_cain"
    },
    {
        name: "Ashley Burns",
        file_name: "ashley_burns"
    },
    {
        name: "Dennis Clay",
        file_name: "dennis_clay"
    },
```

I have also a list of 16 'powers'. Part of it looks like:

```
Tetris.friend_powers = 
[
    {
        name: "speed_2",
        description: "Speed * 2"
    },
    {
        name: "speed_3",
        description: "Speed * 3"
    },
    {
        name: "speed_4",
        description: "Speed * 4"
    },
```

What I want to do is that each name always returns the same power, even if the friends list order is changed. This way I can ensure each friend will always return the same even if for some reason the list changes, for consistency reasons.

So what I'm doing right now is this:

```
let n = Tetris.get_random_int
(
    {
        min: 0,
        max: Tetris.friends.length - 1,
        seed: Tetris.random_3
    }
)

let friend = Tetris.friends[n]
```

...

```
let name = friend.file_name
let seed = new Math.seedrandom(name)

let n = Tetris.get_random_int
(
    {
        min: 0,
        max: Tetris.friend_powers.length - 1,
        seed: seed
    }
)

let power = Tetris.friend_powers[n]
```

So basically I first get a friend with global seed, then make a seed based on the name and use it to get a random powers list index.

This works. The problem is this, when I run a test with all the friends list, this is the distribution:

```
score_2: 7
score_2_d: 4
score_3: 3
score_3_d: 4
score_4: 5
score_4_d: 1
score_5: 6
score_5_d: 7
speed_2: 9
speed_2_d: 5
speed_3: 15
speed_3_d: 3
speed_4: 8
speed_4_d: 9
speed_5: 4
speed_5_d: 10
```

As you can see the probability is not equal or close among each power.
So my question is, how can I distribute the probability more equally, but still having that a friend's name will always return the same ability, regardless of its index, is that even possible? If not I could just use some index based conditionals and try not to change the list's order.

Comment: Couldn't you just store each friends power like `friends[0].power = powers[10]` ?

Comment: And the "rule of big numbers" (it's *Gesetz der großen Zahlen* in german, not sure if I correctly translated it) applies here: For a small group, a random distribution will always look, well, *random*, otherwise it isn't random at all.

Comment: I think you're right. I could just hard code them. I guess I was trying to make the list maintenance easier and more programmatic, but if I add more powers I just add more friends to the list.

Comment: easier? Really? I don't think so ...

Comment: If easy maintenance is the idea, don't use 3 different speed powers. Use one speed power and give it an intensity. Then you can add other powers: "speed", "direction", etc and they can all go from 1 to X, if you so desire, without the need to write "speed_x", "speed_x+1", "speed_x+2" etc in the powers array.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments I'm just going to hardcode a power to each friend.

```
{
    name: "Robin Camacho",
    file_name: "robin_camacho",
    power: "score_5_d"
}
```

Comment: Hardcoded would be if you write `"power": "speed_2"` as a property of a Friend. We're suggesting using "power": 1, with 1 being an index or an id or something inside the powers array. That way you can change the name "speed" to a different labe l( for example when translating the app into a foreign language ) without needing to change the Friends array as well. Basically the same way relational databases work.